# conversion between float and unsigned char [4]

Tags: c++, c

I am using Qt 5 to send data via serial port. The problem comes from a conversion bewteen float and unsigned char [4] with union structure.

```
typedef union {
     float df;
     unsigned char uc4[4];
}fuc4;

fuc4 t1, t2;
t1 = (a+b)/c, t2 = -(a-b)/c;
```

Both is 0 as we can have a look at t1.df and t2.df with qDebug().
However, the last byte of them is quite different where t2.dc[3] is 0x80=128d.
On the other side, I have to use the bytes without any conversion. For example, I need t2.dc[2]*256+t2.dc[3] to get an integer number but it is clearly a mistake if I do so. How can I correct this or do it in a safe way.

Comment: Appreciate any of help.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Would you please help a little cause I saw your answer in another post in which memcpy is recommended.

Comment: that what you'd written wont compile. write real stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always done this one:

```
float f = something;
unsigned char *uc4 = (unsigned char*)&f;
```

You don't need to go through an union for char or unsigned char, though you do for any other types.

Comment: It is solved by adding a 0.0f for each equation. I don't exactly know why it works. Maybe it is about double. Thank you for having another way to do this.